# How to disable WebView scrolling in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I am developing an app for Windows 8.1. I tried below code it's not working.

```xml
<WebView Source="http://wikipedia.org" 
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"/>
```

Is there any JavaScript solution to disable touch, mouse & key board scrolling?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the scroll is JS. How is the page loaded and what are you loading? You could make the view large enough and then use scale transform to fit it in. That's what I've seen other developers do, but there might be other ways. I'm on my phone but I'll put together a demo later when I have my computer. Hope this helps :) That webview is so annoying in so many ways...

Comment: The WebView's scroll bars are shown by the web browser instance, so that's why you can't control them from XAML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used below given JS for my requirement. Though I am waiting for a better (XAML) solution.

```js
function RemoveScrolling() 
{
    var styleElement = document.createElement('style');
    var styleText = 'body, html { overflow: hidden; }'
    var headElements = document.getElementsByTagName('head');
    styleElement.type = 'text/css'; 
    if (headElements.length == 1) 
    { 
       headElements[0].appendChild(styleElement); 
    } 
    else if (document.head) 
    { 
        document.head.appendChild(styleElement); 
    } 
    if (styleElement.styleSheet) 
    { 
        styleElement.styleSheet.cssText = styleText; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Ah, do it in JavaScript.

Comment: Since the browser really is just an instance of Internet Explorer (wrapped), the best way to disable it is to use CSS, as you've done.

Comment: I did a window.addEventListener('load',RemoveScrolling); and it didn't work :(